# convert an int to QByteArray in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to convert an int to `QByteArray`. I'm using this method `QByteArray::number(m_vman);` is it correct?

I'm trying to use the `number()` for getting an int to `QByteArray`.

I'm trying the following code but the *bytearray* is zero

```
    QByteArray vmanByteArray, vheaterByteArray;
    QDataStream streamVMan(&vmanByteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QDataStream streamVHeater(&vheaterByteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    streamVMan << m_vman;
    streamVHeater << m_vheater;

QByteArray arr = m_htman ? vmanByteArray : vheaterByteArray;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing integer to QByteArray using only 4 bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668827/storing-integer-to-qbytearray-using-only-4-bytes)

Comment: Your code works. This question is off-topic as such. You haven't even bothered to check if your own code works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is not zero, your code works fine:

```
#include <QtCore>

QByteArray test(bool m_htman) {
   int m_vman = 1;
   int m_vheater = 2;
   QByteArray vmanByteArray, vheaterByteArray;
   QDataStream streamVMan(&vmanByteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
   QDataStream streamVHeater(&vheaterByteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

   streamVMan << m_vman;
   streamVHeater << m_vheater;

   QByteArray arr=m_htman ?  vmanByteArray: vheaterByteArray;
   return arr;
}

int main() {
   auto one = QByteArray() + '\0' + '\0' + '\0' + '\1';
   auto two = QByteArray() + '\0' + '\0' + '\0' + '\2';
   Q_ASSERT(test(true) == one);
   Q_ASSERT(test(false) == two);
}
```

It may be "zero" if the values stored in it are zeroes, but that'd be correct.

Answer (score 12):

you can simply do like this.

```
int myInt = 123;
QByteArray q_b;
q_b.setNum(myInt);
```

Comment: ::number or .setNum turn number to string, not the actual value.

Answer (score 3):

Related to the actual question title, the following static function should definitely work:

[QByteArray::number](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#number)

Answer (score 2):

I flagged as a duplicate because you could have searched better (seriously, there are dozen of questions like that). Anyway, this is the easiest solution:

```
int myInt;
QByteArray bA;
QDataStream stream(&bA, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream << myInt;
```

Comment: its a boolean variable

Comment: am checking if the m_htman is true, I set the byte array to the result byte array

Comment: You can use ::number() like you are doing but the problem is that you can't work with large numbers

Answer (score 2):

This thread is quite old as I just stumbled across the issue (or a similar one), here is my suggestion:

To store the value of the integer variable (what the value is is not exactly defined here, I mean the memory representation in bytes) in a QByteArray I suggest:

```cpp
QByteArray arr = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&m_vman), sizeof(m_vman));
```

Test case:

```cpp
#include <QtCore>

int main() {
    qint64 intValue = 42;

    QByteArray bytes = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&intValue), sizeof(intValue));

    qDebug() << "intValue: " << intValue;
    qDebug() << "bytes:    " << bytes.toHex(':');
}
```

Output (bytes is little endian representation):

```
intValue:  42
bytes:     "2a:00:00:00:00:00:00:00"
```